# jsf2, primefaces 11, Component ID j_idt20 has already been found in the view

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I am using primefaces 11 in a cluster env(alb + two wildfly 17 + distributable setting). the following error happened when login after session was timeout.

```
2022-04-28 16:28:18,835 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13) java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
2022-04-28 16:28:18,835 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,835 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,835 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,836 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,836 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:459)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,836 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:146)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,836 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1228)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,836 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$2.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:372)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,836 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:127)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,836 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1456)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,836 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,836 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,836 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.restoreView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:358)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,836 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:113)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,836 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:99)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,836 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:272)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,836 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,837 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:101)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,837 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:101)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,837 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:101)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,837 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at deployment.xxxx.war//org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.restoreView(OmniViewHandler.java:100)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,837 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:101)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,837 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:180)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,837 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,837 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:109)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,837 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,837 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,837 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,837 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,837 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,837 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at deployment.cockpit.war//org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:181)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,837 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at deployment.cockpit.war//org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,838 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,838 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,838 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at deployment.cockpit.war//com.github.adminfaces.template.session.AdminFilter.doFilter(AdminFilter.java:155)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,838 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,838 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,838 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,838 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,838 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,838 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,838 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:55)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,838 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,838 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,838 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,838 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,839 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,839 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,839 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,839 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,839 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,839 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,839 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,839 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,839 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,839 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,839 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,839 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,839 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,839 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,839 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,839 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,839 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,840 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,841 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,841 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,841 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,841 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
2022-04-28 16:28:18,841 INFO  [stdout] (default task-13)        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

state saving method is client.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and I added the following setting to save full state for login page and the problem was solved.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FULL_STATE_SAVING_VIEW_IDS</param-name>
    <param-value>/login.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

but I got a new problem, and the error happens occasionally

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID j_idt20 has already been found in the view.
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:1288)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:1272)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:1272)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.application.view.JspStateManagementStrategy.saveView(JspStateManagementStrategy.java:277)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:64)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.application.StateManager.getViewState(StateManager.java:561)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.renderState(PartialViewContextImpl.java:506)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:322)
    at deployment.xxxxxx.war//org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:65)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:228)
    at deployment.xxxxxx.war//org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext.processPartial(OmniPartialViewContext.java:124)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1101)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1647)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:442)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:170)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at deployment.xxxxxx.war//org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.renderView(OmniViewHandler.java:115)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:102)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP02//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:199)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:708)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP02//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at deployment.xxxxxx.war//org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:181)
    at deployment.xxxxxx.war//org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.xxxxxx.war//com.github.adminfaces.template.session.AdminFilter.doFilter(AdminFilter.java:155)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.xxxxxx.war//org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.xxxxxx.war//org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:55)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

how can I solve it? thanks.

Comment: Without your code or a reproducer its impossible to tell what is going on.  And your original issue is here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4260

Comment: Exactly, impossible to tell without looking at your page.
This issue occurs when the view has more than one component with the same id.